# JUnit custom runner with Spring application context

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing, applicationcontext

I am fairly new to Spring and am working with a suite of JUnit 4.7 integration tests for a web application.  I have a number of working test cases of the form:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml" })

public class myTest {
    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
            //execute tests
            ....
    }
}
```

My application has a number of external dependencies that I am testing, all of which have beans that are initialized through the loading of **testContext.xml**.  Some of these external dependencies require custom code to initialize and tear down the necessary resources.

Rather than duplicate this code in every test class that requires it, I would like to encapsulate it into a common location.  My thought was to create a seperate context definition as well as a custom runner that extends **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner** and contains the @ContextConfiguration annotation and related custom code, like so:

```
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

//load the context applicable to this runner
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml" })

public class MyCustomRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyCustomRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);           
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withBeforeClasses(Statement statement) {
        // custom initialization code for resources loaded by testContext.xml
                ...

        return super.withBeforeClasses(statement);
    }

    @Override
    protected Statement withAfterClasses(Statement statement) {
        // custom cleanup code for resources loaded by testContext.xml
                ....

        return super.withAfterClasses(statement);
    }

}
```

I could then have each test class specify its applicable runner with:

```
@RunWith(MyCustomRunner)
```

When I do this, my tests run and the proper **withBeforeClasses** and **withAfterClasses** methods are executed.  However, no applicationContext is provided back to the test class and all of my tests fail with:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Can not load an ApplicationContext
>   with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider
>   annotating your test class with
>   @ContextConfiguration.

The context only loads correctly if I specify the @ContextConfiguration annotation on each test class - ideally, I would like this annotation to live with the handler code for the resources it is responsible for loading.  Which leads me to my question - is it possible to load Spring context information from a custom runner class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a base test class - `@ContextConfiguration` can be inherited, as well as `@Before`, `@After`, and so on:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml" }) 
public abstract class myBaseTest { 
    @Before
    public void init() {
        // custom initialization code for resources loaded by testContext.xml 
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        // custom cleanup code for resources loaded by testContext.xml
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class myTest extends myBaseTest { ... }
```

Comment: Meh, class inheritance in tests.. :/
Is there now, in 2017, a way to do this properly?